# Successful Win10 cumulative update for 21H1 upgrades to 20H2

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

After failing to upgrade my Win10 Home installation to the latest versions, I've performed a clean install of version 1809 (17763) and allowed automatic updates. This way the installation upgraded to version 20H2 (19042) and no other update was found. Then I [downloaded](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=21H1%20x64%202022-05) and installed manually the cumulative update for 21H1 (KB5015020). The update succeeded, but the resulting version remained 19042, [which should correspond to 20H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions#Personal_computer_versions).

**Q:** How do I upgrade to 21H1 (19043)? Win10 20H2 [reached its end-of-servicing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/windows-10-20h2-end-of-servicing), already.

```
>systeminfo

.....
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19042 N/A Build 19042
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Original Install Date:     29.05.2022, 9:42:35
System Boot Time:          29.05.2022, 10:25:46
System Manufacturer:       LENOVO
System Model:              81LK
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel ~2400 Mhz
BIOS Version:              LENOVO BGCN33WW, 24.11.2020
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume2
.....
Total Physical Memory:     16 264 MB
Available Physical Memory: 12 954 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  19 208 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 14 955 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    4 253 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              \\DESKTOP-25SQ01H
Hotfix(s):                 5 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB5013624
                           [02]: KB4562830
                           [03]: KB5007401
                           [04]: KB5015020
                           [05]: KB5014032
.....
```

Comment: It's impossible to downgrade from Windows 10 21H1 to Windows 10 20H2. KB5015020 wouldn't have updated your system to Windows 10 21H2.  You should be using the [Update Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-update-assistant-3550dfb2-a015-7765-12ea-fba2ac36fb3f) to upgrade to Windows 10 21H2. I don't recommend the Media Creation Tool in a case like this.  Feature updates are NOT installed through Cumulative updates, while they can be installed through Windows Update, they are not linked to a KB update.  This means they cannot be downloaded from the update catalog

Comment: I am willing to submit an answer but I would need to see the output of `winver` to understand the exact build you are on.

Comment: @Ramhound `winver` says "20H2 (19042.1708)"

Comment: That means you are still running Windows 10 20H2.  This matches the build for KB5015020, I know you might have thought you updated to Windows 10 21H1 but that didn't actually happen.  I would use the Update Assistant in order to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I upgrade to 21H1 (19043)? Win10 20H2 reached its end-of-servicing, already.

There are two ways of upgrading to the current version of Windows 10 21H2.  You can either download the ISO through the [Media Creation Tool](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209) or use the [Update Assistant](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799445).

If you actually want to upgrade to Windows 10 21H1 then you will have to download the [Windows 10 21H1 ISO](https://uupdump.net/), mount it within Windows, and run the setup.exe in order to upgrade your installation to that specific version.

> Then I downloaded and installed manually the cumulative update for 21H1 (KB5015020). The update succeeded, but the resulting version remained 19042, which should correspond to 20H2.

The update you downloaded is a Windows 10 20H2 cumulative update.  You did not actually upgrade to Windows 10 21H1 by installing that update. My suggested solution, to this problem, is using the Update Assistant, to upgrade to Windows 21H2 which is the currently supported version of Windows 10.