# Updating from Windows 10 version 1809 to 21H2

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to download some sort of installer that I can run on a Windows 10 machine and update to either 21H2 or the latest version? I'm having trouble figuring out if this is even possible or if you have to use the Windows update service.

The update needs to happen on a machine with a very limited internet connection, so I have to make sure that the update doesn't use to much data

Comment: Just download the 21H2, which isn’t currently supported and won’t be receiving updates, simply mount the ISO within Windows and run the setup.

Comment: That means gigabytes of data right? There's no way of updating without that gigantic ISO?

Comment: No; There is no way of installing the feature update without actually downloading the feature update. If you want slightly less data downloaded update through Windows Update

Comment: I wasn't sure if that ISO contained a complete Windows install or if it was possible to extract only the new features and get a much smaller update. But if that's the size of the feature update itself then I have my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said if you want slightly less download just let Windows update itself, otherwise, if that can’t be done the ISO or [Windows 10 Update Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-update-assistant-3550dfb2-a015-7765-12ea-fba2ac36fb3f) are your two options. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1723818/successful-win10-cumulative-update-for-21h1-upgrades-to-20h2/1723829#1723829) isn’t a perfect duplicate but I have answered your question in the past.

Comment: Download the ISO on a machine with faster Internet and do it that way. That works. I have done it.

Comment: As @Ramhound states, reinstalling (keeping files) from ISO is by far the fastest and most reliable way to get to the most current version of Windows. It also will download *less* data in total than performing all the many updates would.